# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying to run app on the iphone 6 and I get this error. I get the error after making the facebook login. Normally, it is working successfully on the simulator. I couldn't find why it gives the error.

Error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x181dcae38 0x18142ff80 0x181d41a6c 0x100418620 0x100417aa0 0x10042dbac 0x10006a3a0 0x10006aa0c 0x186f14b40 0x186f14744 0x1872ba9fc 0x1872774f4 0x187273f04 0x1871c6fd8 0x1871d4990 0x186f064a4 0x181d807b0 0x181d7e554 0x181d7e984 0x181ca8d10 0x183590088 0x186f7df70 0x10008810c 0x1818468b8)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you posted no stack trace, I assume you want to learn how to find bugs like this. First, in Xcode, set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions, so you find where exactly the crash happens.

The error says clearly that you are trying to access array [0] for an NSArray that is empty. Once you find the location of the crash that should be easy to find.